# Can I use CLR integration with dotnet 6 on linux?

Tags: sql-server, docker

We have used CLR integration in the past and it was great.

Now we're migrating to .NET 6 and we work on Linux (Debian & Ubuntu).

We use SQL Server Docker.

Is it possible to write CLR integration using .NET 6 and run it on Linux-based SQL Server container?

Comment: Asking a yes or no question might not be the best of ideas.

Comment: Short answer: no. No edition/version of SQL Server supports .NET Core (which .NET 6 is). Language Extensions should allow you to run such code, but the [current version](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-language-extensions/tree/main/language-extensions/dotnet-core-CSharp) is .NET 5 and only available for Windows, so not much is happening there.

Comment: @JeroenMostert the version was bumped to 6 but that was the only change in the last 2 years. It still depends on an ancient version of `Microsoft.Data.Analysis` for the not-quite-Dataframe.  It seems the C# extension was just a proof-of-concept if not an intern project. If they were serious about it they'd target F#